# mapping list of objects using automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm using automapper in order to map objects on the fly.

```
public class CarProfile : Profile
{
    public CarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Car, CarVM>();
        CreateMap<CarVM, Car>();
        CreateMap<List<Car>, List<CarVM>>();
        CreateMap<List<CarVM>, List<Car>>();            
    }
}

List<Car> cars = ... get data()...
List<CarVM> vmList = new List<CarVM>();

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    vmList.Add(mapper.Map<Car>(item));
}
```

This works but I want to map list instead of each object in the list inside foreach, so I tried

```
 vmList.AddRange(mapper.Map<List<Car>>(cars));
```

and I'm getting no exception or error but no objects in the vmList.
What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `List` mappings.

```
CreateMap<List<Car>, List<CarVM>>();
CreateMap<List<CarVM>, List<Car>>();
```

You only need the singular mappings.
The plural/list ones come out-of-the-box, see the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html).

```
CreateMap<Car, CarVM>();
CreateMap<CarVM, Car>();
```

---

You probably also meant: `mapper.Map<List<CarVM>>(cars)`.